# extract formula from OLS Regression Results

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

My Goal is: Extracting the formula (not only the coefs) after a linear regression done with statsmodel.

Context :
I have a pandas dataframe ,

```
df
      x    y     z 

0   0.0  2.0    54.200
1   0.0  2.2    70.160
2   0.0  2.4    89.000
3   0.0  2.6    110.960
```

i 'am doing a linear regression using ***statsmodels.api*** (2 variables, polynomial degree=3) , i'am happy with this regression.

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      z   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 2.193e+29
Date:                Sun, 31 May 2020   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        22:04:49   Log-Likelihood:                 9444.6
No. Observations:                 400   AIC:                        -1.887e+04
Df Residuals:                     390   BIC:                        -1.883e+04
Df Model:                           9                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.2000   3.33e-11   6.01e+09      0.000       0.200       0.200
x1             2.0000   1.16e-11   1.72e+11      0.000       2.000       2.000
x2             1.0000   2.63e-11    3.8e+10      0.000       1.000       1.000
x3             4.0000   3.85e-12   1.04e+12      0.000       4.000       4.000
x4            12.0000   4.36e-12   2.75e+12      0.000      12.000      12.000
x5             3.0000   6.81e-12   4.41e+11      0.000       3.000       3.000
x6             6.0000   5.74e-13   1.05e+13      0.000       6.000       6.000
x7            13.0000   4.99e-13    2.6e+13      0.000      13.000      13.000
x8            14.0000   4.99e-13   2.81e+13      0.000      14.000      14.000
x9             5.0000   5.74e-13   8.71e+12      0.000       5.000       5.000
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       25.163   Durbin-Watson:                   0.038
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               28.834
Skew:                          -0.655   Prob(JB):                     5.48e-07
Kurtosis:                       2.872   Cond. No.                     6.66e+03
==============================================================================
```

I need to implement that outside of python , (ms excel) , I would like to know the formula.

I know it is polynomial deg3 , but I wondering how to know which coeff apply to which term of 
the equation. Something like that :

[image: Equation_image]

*For exemple : x7 coeef is the coeff for x³ ,y², x²y , ... ?*

***Note:*** this is a simplify version of my problem , in reallity I have 3 variables ,  deg:3 so 20 coefs.

This is a simpler exemple of code to get started with my case:

```py
# %% Question extract formula from linear regresion coeff
#Import
import numpy as np   # version : '1.18.1'
import pandas as pd  # version'1.0.0'

import statsmodels.api as sm   # version : '0.10.1'
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

from itertools import product


#%% Creating the dummies datas
def function_for_df(row):
    x= row['x']
    y= row['y']
    return  unknow_function(x,y)

def unknow_function(x,y):
    """ 
     This is to generate the datas , of  course in reality I do not know the formula
    """
    r =0.2+ \
       6*x**3+4*x**2+2*x+ \
       5*y**3+3*y**2+1*y+ \
       12*x*y + 13*x**2*y+ 14*x*y**2
    return r

# input data
x_input = np.arange(0, 4 , 0.2)
y_input = np.arange(2, 6 , 0.2)

# create a simple dataframe with dummies datas
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(x_input, y_input)), columns=['x', 'y'])
df['z'] = df.apply(function_for_df, axis=1)

# In the reality I start from there !

#%%  creating the model
X = df[['x','y']].astype(float) #
Y = df['z'].astype(float) 

polynomial_features_final= PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X3 = polynomial_features_final.fit_transform(X)

model = sm.OLS(Y, X3).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X3) 

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)

#%% using the model to make predictions, no problem
def model_predict(x_sample, y_samples):
    df_input = pd.DataFrame({  "x":x_sample, "y":y_samples }, index=[0])
    X_input = polynomial_features_final.fit_transform(df_input)
    prediction = model.predict(X_input)
    return prediction

print("prediction for x=2, y=3.2 :" ,model_predict(2 ,3.2))

# How to extract the formula for the "model" ?
#Thanks
```

**Side notes:**

A desciption like the one given by pasty ModelDesc will be fine:

```py
from patsy import ModelDesc
ModelDesc.from_formula("y ~ x")

# or even better :

desc = ModelDesc.from_formula("y ~ (a + b + c + d) ** 2")
desc.describe()
```

But i 'am not able to make the bridge between my model and patsy.ModelDesc.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a question about how sklearn PolynomialFeature creates the design matrix. There is no information about this available to the statsmodels model

Comment: @Josef , Thanks for you help, I will dig more in  PolynomialFeature, in fact I use it as it is the only way I found to prepare easily my data for a deg=3. But if there is a way prepare the data for  deg=3 without PolynomialFeature , i'am happy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

As Josef said in the comment, i had to look at : sklearn PolynomialFeature .

Then I found this answer :

```py
    PolynomialFeatures(degree=3).get_feature_names()
```

In the context :

```py
    #%%  creating the model
    X = df[['x','y']].astype(float) #
    Y = df['z'].astype(float) 

    polynomial_features_final= PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
    #X3 = polynomial_features_final.fit_transform(X)

    X3 = polynomial_features_final.fit_transform(df[['x', 'y']].to_numpy())

    model = sm.OLS(Y, X3).fit()
    predictions = model.predict(X3) 

    print_model = model.summary()
    print(print_model)

    print("\n-- ONE SOLUTION --\n Coef and Term name :")
    results = list(zip(model.params, polynomial_features_final.get_feature_names()))
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fit the model using Patsy formula language using [`statsmodels.formula.api`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html)

For instance, you can have:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# You do not need fit_transform to generate poly features in df
# You can specify the model using vectorized functions, many transformations are supported
model = smf.ols(formula='z ~ x*y + I(x**2)*I(y**2) + I(x**3)*I(y**3)', data=df).fit()
print_model = model.summary()

print(print_model)
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      z   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 4.193e+05
Date:                Tue, 15 Feb 2022   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        16:53:19   Log-Likelihood:                -1478.1
No. Observations:                 400   AIC:                             2976.
Df Residuals:                     390   BIC:                             3016.
Df Model:                           9                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=======================================================================================
                          coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             229.3425     23.994      9.558      0.000     182.168     276.517
x                    -180.0081     11.822    -15.226      0.000    -203.251    -156.765
y                    -136.2619     19.039     -7.157      0.000    -173.694     -98.830
x:y                   118.0431      2.864     41.210      0.000     112.411     123.675
I(x ** 2)              31.2537      4.257      7.341      0.000      22.884      39.624
I(y ** 2)              22.5973      4.986      4.532      0.000      12.795      32.399
I(x ** 2):I(y ** 2)     1.4176      0.213      6.671      0.000       1.000       1.835
I(x ** 3)               4.7562      0.595      7.991      0.000       3.586       5.926
I(y ** 3)               4.7601      0.423     11.250      0.000       3.928       5.592
I(x ** 3):I(y ** 3)     0.0166      0.006      2.915      0.004       0.005       0.028
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       28.012   Durbin-Watson:                   0.182
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               71.076
Skew:                          -0.311   Prob(JB):                     3.68e-16
Kurtosis:                       4.969   Cond. No.                     1.32e+05
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The condition number is large, 1.32e+05. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.

print(model.params)
Intercept              229.342451
x                     -180.008082
y                     -136.261886
x:y                    118.043098
I(x ** 2)               31.253705
I(y ** 2)               22.597298
I(x ** 2):I(y ** 2)      1.417551
I(x ** 3)                4.756205
I(y ** 3)                4.760144
I(x ** 3):I(y ** 3)      0.016611
dtype: float64
```

Then by simple `print(model.params)`,  you will have a natural bridge between the model and patsy.ModelDesc (here that is analogous to the formula definition)

Notes: Raw polynomial used here in the demo. You may switch to using orthogonal polynomials. That will help explain the contribution of each term to variance in the outcome, ref to [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/433190)